# Can you disable certain menus without resorting to custom firmware?

Tags: psp

I think there are way too many menus on my PSP that I will never use, like the Extras Menu, Videos and Music etc. 
Is there a way to remove those without resorting to a custom firmware?

If not, is there custom firmware that allows that while still being able to play my legally owned games?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in the original firmware. You'll need custom firmware for this.

The good news is, custom firmware these days is dead easy to install: update the PSP to the latest official version, drag and drop the installer onto the PSP, and run it. It also doesn't interfere with legally acquired games - you just put the game in the drive and play normally. And if it does turn out to interfere with one of your games, the most popular custom firmware, [PRO CFW version C2](https://code.google.com/p/procfw/), boots into the plain Sony firmware and needs to explicitly activated afterwards - so if you're having problems, just reboot the PSP and you're running the plain firmware again.

Once you have custom firmware installed, plugins like [XMB Item Hider](http://www.dashhacks.com/psp/homebrew-apps/xrossmediabar-item-hider-v13fix2-released.html) can be used to customize the main menu.

Comment: For the record, custom firmware doesn't mean piracy - it is entirely possible to have custom firmware for homebrew or other reasons and still you know, not pirate games.